# DynamoDB fine grained access control - group membership

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I'm building an app where users should only be able to access entries in a table that belong to them. It's straightforward to achieve this by adding an IAM condition that the leading keys must equal the user's login ID, for example, from Cognito or Facebook login.

However, now I'm trying to add a functionality that allows entries to be accessed by multiple users in the same group. Is this possible using the IAM conditions, or do I need to set up a server in the middle to handle the group membership logic?